# One of configurations from matrix gets cancelled every time

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have two projects and with dependencies so that project A is started, it updates files from git and then runs a multi-configuration project B, which:

- has three axes: "foo", "bar" and "baz" with 11 x 4 x 2 items

  I'm going to call the values like fooN for item N from axis foo, etc.
- has a configuration filter, ruling out the last axis by running only when
  `baz=="baz1"` (maybe in a later phase we'll want to run also tests with `baz2`
  for baz)
- runs a shell script that only `cd`s and calls python interpreter with a script

  ```
  cd /path/to/scripts
  python test_${bar}.py
  ```

So when the project is run, I expect 44 configurations to be tested.  But only 43 are.

It's always the same configuration (which happens to be the last one triggered, as Jenkins seems to remember the order(?)) that does never run at all:

- in the final matrix looks as a gray dot with "Disabled" tooltip
- in Console output, after saying "Triggering bazN,barN,fooN" for all 44 combinations,
  then "bazN,barN,fooN completed with result SUCCESS" for all except the last one, but
  the last one seems to be always cancelled/aborted:

  > ```
  > baz1,bar7,foo3 appears to be cancelled
  > baz1,bar7,foo3 completed with result ABORTED
  > ```
- Console output for the single combination is not available---it looks like it never
  has been built
- Jenkins log does not show anything interesting about "baz1,bar7,foo3"

What does this mean?  Any other pointers how to troubleshoot this?

**Edit:** I tried adding a "HTTP ping" script to the repo and called it from above script,
          just before the `python test_${bar}.py` part.  Which proved that for the affected
          configuration, Jenkins does not even run those lines.

Answer (score 9):

Without knowing how you got here to begin with (probably a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19179)):

Append `configure` to the URL of the disabled configuration, and in the resulting form, uncheck *Disabled* and *Save*.

Comment: Wow... did not know there is configuration per matrix configuration. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but as a workaround to the problem, cloning whole project to a new one helped: with the new project, all configurations ran normally.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved Jenkins issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19179

By the Matrix Project plug-in, version 1.4:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin